# Call to undefined function pg_escape_string()

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

Here is the error message:

```
Fatal error:  Call to undefined function pg_escape_string() in ...
```

I have installed php, postgresql and pdo_pgsql all through homebrew

```
> php -v
PHP 5.5.30 (cli) (built: Oct  3 2015 23:48:03) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies

> postgres --version
postgres (PostgreSQL) 9.4.5

> sw_vers 
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.11.1
BuildVersion:   15B42

> php -i
pdo_pgsql
PDO Driver for PostgreSQL => enabled
PostgreSQL(libpq) Version => 9.4.4
Module version => 1.0.2
```

Other functions for working with postgre in php are working fine (connect, query,...)

Comment: Do you get error while connecting to DB?

Comment: Do you use PDO for connections or legacy pg_ functions